Usrmerge error armbian
I'm trying to install linux on a old Player TV Box from amazon.
For this I have get my CPU (s905w) and armbian for this configuration, I'm now on linux with my machine.
Problem :
I cant upgrade or install package because :
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  systemd udev
Suggested packages:
  systemd-container systemd-homed systemd-userdbd systemd-boot libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0 libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0 libtss2-rc0 libtss2-tcti-device0
Recommended packages:
  networkd-dispatcher systemd-hwe-hwdb
The following packages will be upgraded:
  systemd udev
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 225 not upgraded.
39 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5255 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 34895 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../systemd_255.4-1ubuntu7_arm64.deb ...


******************************************************************************
*
* The systemd package cannot be installed because this system does
* not have a merged /usr.
*
* Please install the usrmerge package to convert this system to merged-/usr.
*
* For more information please read https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge.
*
******************************************************************************


dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd_255.4-1ubuntu7_arm64.deb (--unpack):
 new systemd package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting file flags is only supported on regular files and directories, cannot set on '/var/log/journal'.
Setting file flags is only supported on regular files and directories, cannot set on '/var/log/journal'.
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of systemd, which would be broken by installation of udev ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure systemd (broken by udev)
Preparing to unpack .../udev_255.4-1ubuntu7_arm64.deb ...
De-configuring systemd (255.4-1ubuntu5), to allow installation of udev (255.4-1ubuntu7) ...


******************************************************************************
*
* The udev package cannot be installed because this system does
* not have a merged /usr.
*
* Please install the usrmerge package to convert this system to merged-/usr.
*
* For more information please read https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge.
*
******************************************************************************


dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_255.4-1ubuntu7_arm64.deb (--unpack):
 new udev package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting file flags is only supported on regular files and directories, cannot set on '/var/log/journal'.
Setting file flags is only supported on regular files and directories, cannot set on '/var/log/journal'.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd_255.4-1ubuntu7_arm64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_255.4-1ubuntu7_arm64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

And I try to install usrmerge with apt :
sudo apt-get install usrmerge

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package usrmerge is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'usrmerge' has no installation candidate

If you have any idea thank you very much. Cordialy.

I have a little new, when I've moved "lib64" folder from / to /user and create symbolic link in / for him, its working, but I dont know if its a good thing..
